# W3c validation more than 20 redirects errors?

Tags: w3c-validation

I am trying to validate my website on `w3 validator` and I am getting this error message called `IO Error: Maximum redirects (20) exceeded`. I don't know what is causing this error. Please help me. Bellow is the screenshot of error.

[image: IO Error: Maximum redirects (20) exceeded]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this error the redirection error message on w3 validator was due to one of the redirect functions in my controller. I checked everywhere other than the controller but now its working fine.